# Send HTTP queue through ZeroMQ

Tags: php, api, zeromq

I have my own web application which uses third party API's through which thousand of HTTP request being sent daily.

I want to know if i send HTTP request through ZeroMQ. Will ZeroMQ able to prioritise the HTTP request in queue and is this a good way to send HTTP request through ZeroMQ?

Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Here the answer from [manual](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#-MQ-is-Not-a-Neutral-Carrier).

> The answer used to be "this is not how it works". ØMQ is not a neutral carrier: it imposes a framing on the transport protocols it uses. This framing is not compatible with existing protocols, which tend to use their own framing.

And next one (optimistic) in same chapter:

> Since v3.3, however, ØMQ has a socket option called ZMQ_ROUTER_RAW that lets you read and write data without the ØMQ framing. You could use this to read and write proper HTTP requests and responses.

Comment: Thanks for the info but is it feasible to use ZeroMQ for handling HTTP requests? Does ZeroMQ keep the requests in queue and priorities it?

Comment: It depends on architecture of your solution. In general answer is yes - see maillist http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2013-June/021682.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745084/rabbitmq-and-message-priority