# How to listen to multiple queues in order of priority in a Mule application.

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, esb, mule-studio

I have a amqp connector setup that listens on a single queue for JSON messages and is working fine. The business has dropped a use case that my application now needs to listen on multiple queues in order of priority. For example having three queues:

1. HighQ
2. NormalQ
3. LowQ

I want the mule connector to first read from HighQ until empty, then NormalQ until empty and LowQ until empty. Restarting from HighQ after every message.

I feel like this should be standard but my google foo is failing me.

Any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

In the usecase you specified I think it would be better to go with a single queue, but posting messages with 3 priority levels.

THis way the messages are always read in the order of their priority with the highest prioritymessage are always read first.

So you can make the message producers to post the messages onto the queue with 3 priority levels(say 9 for high , 4 for normal, 0 for low).

You inbound JMS endpoint will read all the messages with priority of 9 first. Then it will read all the messages with priotiy of 4 and then the messages with priority of 0.

Sample JMS Outbound posting messages with priority.

```
<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="StudioOUT" connector-ref="MyAppJMS" doc:name="JMS">
        <set-property propertyName="Priority" value="9"/> 
</jms:outbound-endpoint>
```

I hope this should address your scenario.

More on priority of JMS.
http://www.christianposta.com/blog/?p=289

Comment: would this work for AMQP servers like AMQP? and If the messages are first-in-first-out, how can I read the priority from the message content itself or its property? is this something specific to JMS? (i.e. JMS can say give me all priority 9 messages in the queue without affecting the order of the rest?) I thought the point of queue's was to maintain order

Comment: You don't need to wory about the first in and first out. That happens only when all the messages are with same priority. If some messages have igher priority they will always be read first irrespective f when they were posted. Priority is inbuilt into the JMS read. You don't need to configure anything extra to read high priority first. The only coding to be done is while posting the messages to queue, post them with proper priority bbased in its importance as per your business logic.

Comment: I agree with @user1760178 that you shall not try to reproduce a priority delivery mechanism with several queues but instead use a single queue and use a JMS / AMQP broker that honours the priority property of messages.

Comment: Guys, the design of the Queues is not in my control. The architecture i've been given is RabbitMQ multiple queues and Mule ESB. If this is so complicated that it cannot be done, then I'll just tell them it cannot be done. But I know it can be done in a dirty way (Code it myself in Java), I was just looking for a clean solution from Mule itself.

Comment: Enjoy the free 300 point upgrade. #disappointed I can't even down-vote now lol reputation from 367 down to 67. First and last time i'm doing a bounty.

Comment: You have to accept the answer for me to get the bounty. That bounty is gone. it went to no one.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with message priority is really something that your broker should handle. Dealing with this yourself can be tricky and cumbersome.

Processing queues sequentially in order to simulate priority seems like a bad idea. Lets say you've processed all messages from the high priority queue and start processing the normal priority queue.

While processing the normal priority queue new messages are coming in on the high priority queue. These high priority messages will be sitting there until both the normal and low priority queues are entirely processed.

You could probably improve your mechanism to handle situations like this a bit better, but it will be hard to make it bullet proof. You really don't want to deal with stuff like this yourself.

The JMS api has the concept of 'message priority' built in, but that's of little use to U if you aren't using a JMS broker.

If you're using rabbit mq then you should have a look at this stackoverflow post: [rabbitmq-and-message-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745084/rabbitmq-and-message-priority).
As Rabbit MQ queues are basically FIFO queues there's no easy way to use "real" prioritized message (such as in JMS).

There is however a plugin that claims to provide the functionality that you are looking for: [rabbitmq-priority-queue](http://rabbitmq-priority-queue).
According to the documentation the next version of RabbitMQ (3.5.0) will support prioritized queues out of the box.

If using the plugin isn't an option and if the priority of the messages is really important then I would not use the pattern you described using multiple queues. The pattern also doesn't scale very well if more priority levels are needed. I would opt to receive all the messages on a single channel (given that each message has a property that represents the priority level) and forward them to a (non amqp) new channel that handles the [resequencing](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/Resequencer.html) for you. An open-source product that could help you with this is [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html) but there are also other options available.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can't use the new version of rabbitmq yet (deployed in prod) Yes, already said JMS won't be useful and I disagree that this is a terrible idea. Your example is wrong. I will always start processing from the high-priority queue. For example if i processed a normal queue message, the next time I "poll" is from the high-priority queue so I will see that message that came in while i was processing the normal priority message. Check High, Check Med, Check, Low, Repeat. If I get a message at any "check", I will process it and start again with Check High.