# RabbitMQ Message Priority Queue Not working

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I run priority queue [java program](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue/blob/3431dc1ef8ea53e9a556c6be8bc1b417ac03b58d/examples/java/src/com/rabbitmq/examples/PriorityQueue.java) in my eclipse, I got an issue, First time I got correct answer. Another time i added one more message in queue, but this time i got different result.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
     ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
        Channel ch = conn.createChannel();
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        args.put("x-max-priority", 10);
        ch.queueDeclare(QUEUE_UPDATE, true, false, false, args);

         publish(ch, 141);   
         publish(ch, 250);   

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        ch.basicConsume(QUEUE_UPDATE, true, new DefaultConsumer(ch) {
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("Received " + new String(body));
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        latch.await();
        conn.close();           
        System.out.println("Finished");
}

private static void publish(Channel ch, int priority) throws Exception {
     BasicProperties props = MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC.builder().priority(priority).build();
     String body = QUEUE_UPDATE + " message with priority " + priority ;
     ch.basicPublish("", QUEUE_UPDATE, props, body.getBytes());         
}
```

correct output:

```
Received update-queue message with priority 250
Received update-queue message with priority 141
Finished
```

added one more queue message

```
         publish(ch, 141);    
         publish(ch, 250);   
         publish(ch, 110); // newly added
```

Expected output

```
Received update-queue message with priority 250
Received update-queue message with priority 141
Received update-queue message with priority 110
Finished
```

Actual output

```
Received update-queue message with priority 141
Received update-queue message with priority 250
Received update-queue message with priority 110
Finished
```

How it came like this? Anything I did wrong?

Comment: Delete the queue and try using this: `args.put("x-max-priority", 250);`

Comment: For C# developers who stumble upon this question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221020/rabbitmq-3-5-and-message-priority/38999171#38999171 .  In a nutshell, "push api" does not respect .Priority.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. What worked for me is defining a limit as defined by the [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html), for example `channel.basicQos(1);`.
If you don't set this limit the messages are delivered to the consumers as they arrive at the broker, so they are never sorted using the priority.

When you set a low limit the broker won't send more messages than this limit at a time, thus sorting messages before delivery.

Comment: Thanks a lot Toresan! It's working 100% if I could I would mark it as correct answer!

Comment: i tried but it didnt work, @GeorgeAnisimov how you made it work? what code you added